# How can I extract part of a string that is in quotes

Tags: ruby, string

Say I have this string:

```
foo = "This is a string 'with a string inside it!'"
```

How do I extract 'with a string inside it!' from `foo`?

Comment: It depends on how your string is, but something like this might work: `foo[/'.+'/]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo = "This is a string 'with a string inside it!'"
foo[foo.index("'")..foo.rindex("'")]
#=> "'with a string inside it!'"
```

Comment: While this works with the OP's example, it will fail to do the right thing with two embedded single-quoted strings.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes,that was not asked by `OP`. If he demand that, I have answer for that too. So what was not asked,I will not guess about that.BTW, lot's here do guess when any question comes to `SO`. But I am not such. So you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo[/('.+')/, 1]
 => "'with a string inside it!'"
```

This is using a [regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html). This particular syntax returns the first match.

Comment: OP wants `'with a string inside it!'`

Comment: That wasn't very clear from the question, but I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use non-greedy quantifier

```
foo[/'.*?'/]
```